# Using different normalization methods in R

Tags: r, normalization

I ran a k-means clustering algorithm using software called Predixion about 6 months ago. I wrote an R script that would hopefully reproduce the same results from Predixion. However, the results are very different. I believe the results are different because we normalized the data differently. I need to be able to use different normalization methods for each column.

```
account = c("A","B","C", "D","E")
var_num1= c(67,69,71,33,19)
var_num2= c(7175,12018, 6075, 3128, 4002)
var_percent= c(.22,.57,.33,.87,.62)
df = data.frame(account, var_num1,var_num2, var_percent)
```

I'd like to use log normalization on column 'var_num1'. I'd like to use Min/Max Normalization for columns 'var_num2' and 'var_percent'.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: So... what have you tried so far (in R)? What is your expected output?

Comment: For other clustering projects, I've simply used:
`df=scale(df)`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
df$var_num1 <- scale(df$var_num1)
```

This takes the values of one column and scales them. The same thing can be done with the other columns and different scaling methods.

Edit:
One possibility for a Min/Max Normalization:

```
df$var_num1_minmax <- lapply(df$var_num1, function(x) (x-min(df$var_num1))/(max(df$var_num1)-min(df$var_num1)))
```

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. However, I'm wondering how to write other methods of normalization outside of the scale() function.

Comment: I edited my answer above and added a Min/Max normalization. Hope this completely answers your question.

Comment: Thank you very much. Are you familiar with log normalization? Do you know how to do that for 1 column?

Comment: `log2(df$var_num1)` :)